# Function with the same domain as data loaded into pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot data an analyze how well it fits a predicted behaviour.
I use pgfplots to plot the data using the command `\addplot[color=black,mark=x,only marks] table {data.dat};` I would like to plot a function on top of the data using the command `\addplot[color=black,mark=none] {x*x};`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}

    \addplot table {
    1 1
    2 4.3
    3 8.7
    4 15.3
    };

    \addplot[color=black,mark=none] {x*x};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the domain of the function does not necessarily match the domain of the data. I could specify the domain of the function explicitly to match the min/max of my data, but I am importing the data from somewhere else and those values might change occasionally. Is there a way to adjust the function domain automatically?

Answer (score 3):

PGFPlots stores the limits of the data it has encountered so far in macros called `\pgfplots@xmin`, `\pgfplots@xmax`, and so on. You can use these to specify the range of your function domain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfplotsxmin}{\pgfplots@xmin}
\newcommand{\pgfplotsxmax}{\pgfplots@xmax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}

    \addplot table {
    1 1
    2 4.3
    3 8.7
    4 15.3
    };

    \addplot [
            color=black,
            mark=none,
        domain=\pgfplotsxmin:\pgfplotsxmax] {x*x};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Much cleaner than mine... :) I looked for something like this and everything I read said they weren't computed until `\end{axis}`.